# ping google.com within the Oracle Linux 9.1 VM is not working

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, oracle-linux, ipv4

I have installed the Oracle VM VirtualBox in my laptop. Then I downloaded the Full ISO image for Oracle Linux 9.1 version (via https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-isos.html) and used that in order to create an Oracle Linux (64 bit) virtual machine. The installation was successful and I was able to login to my VM.

I can ssh from my laptop to my Linux VM without any issues. I can browse the internet within the Linux machine.

I opened up a terminal and executed the below command

```
ping google.com
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't send any replies.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com(bom12s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:80f::200e)) 56 data bytes
--- google.com ping statistics ---
113 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 114760ms
```

I did `nslookup google.com` as well as `cat /etc/resol.conf`. Name server details are fetched properly

I am not sure whether I am missing something here since I can access internet via an internet browser within Linux VM.

Your thoughts and opinions are much appreciated.

**Result of resolvectl status**

```
[root@localhost ~]# resolvectl status
bash: resolvectl: command not found...
Install package 'systemd-resolved' to provide command 'resolvectl'? [N/y] y

 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Loading list of packages.... 

The following packages have to be installed:

 systemd-resolved-250-12.0.1.el9_1.x86_64   System daemon that provides network name resolution to local applications

Proceed with changes? [N/y] y

 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Waiting for authentication... 
 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Downloading packages... 
 * Requesting data... 
 * Testing changes... 
 * Installing packages... 

Failed to get global data: Could not activate remote peer.
```

**Result of nslookup google.com**

```
Server:     X.X.X.X
Address:    X.X.X.X#98

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.199.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2567:7845:4756:74e::352e
```

**Result of grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver X.X.X.X
nameserver fe35::f2db:74ff:fe65:576f%enp0s3
```

Please note that the Server value and nameserver value in nslookup and grep commands are identical.

Cheers

Comment: can you `ping 8.8.8.8` from the VM? also try `ping google.com -4`

Comment: @paxamus Yes, both of them worked like a charm. Any ideas what is happening??

Comment: Please edit your question and post the result of `sudo resolvectl status`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Posted the result of sudo resolvectl status

Comment: Oops, you don't have it installed. You didn't need to install it anyways. Please post the result of `nslookup google.com` and `grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have provided the requested info

Comment: Maybe enable ipv6 on your virtual box network, for example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/803102/virtualbox-no-ipv6-in-ubuntu-guest-win10-host
or maybe take out the ipv6 nameserver.

Comment: Name resolution works just fine. Damn, I'm inattentive, I'm not sure IPv6 works in VirtualBox. `ping -4 host` should work for you.

Comment: taking out the ipv6 nameserver does the trick @paxamus. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [user manual](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf) IPv6 by default is disabled for guests using the NAT adapter.

- You could try to change the guest network adapter to Bridged *if* you have IPv6 enabled on your LAN (network connections should be restarted in the guest or you could simply reboot it).

or

- You could enable IPv6 using `VBoxManage natnetwork modify --netname natnet1 --ipv6=on` (to find out all NAT network adapters run `VBoxManage natnetwork list`).

Anyways, `ping -4 host.com` should work.

Comment: Or you could just make your guest prefer IPv4 connections: https://serverfault.com/questions/93717/setting-ipv4-as-preferred-protocol-over-ipv6 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428736/how-to-make-my-system-centos-7-use-primarily-ipv4-if-its-available In this case you can still use NAT.

Comment: I ran VBoxManage natnetwork list and it showed>>
NAT Networks:
0 networks found (I have 2 Adapters. Adapter 1 being Bridged and Adapter 2 being NAT)

Plus without any issues ping -4 google.com works but ping google.com doesn't

Comment: This fixed the issue. Many Thanks for your help @Artem